# setClientProgramName in DataSource

Tags: java, db2, datasource, tomcat9, db2-luw

In `tomcat9` there is a setting in `context.xml`:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/db2xx"         auth="Container"    
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"     driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" 
    maxTotal="100"                  maxIdle="30"      
    maxWaitMillis="-1"              username="xx" password="xx"         
    url="jdbc:db2://xxxx:xxx/dbname;" />
```

and in `Java` is :

```
    try {
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource");
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource ds = (com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/db2xx");
        ds.setClientProgramName("MyApplication");
        conn = ds.getConnection();
    }
```

But I get error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource cannot be cast to com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource
```

Do I have to change

`org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource`

where ?
The main point is

`ds.setClientProgramName("MyApplication");`

because I would like to see

`MyApplication` in  `APPLICATION_NAME`

when I run

`SELECT  APPLICATION_NAME  FROM  TABLE(MON_GET_CONNECTION(CAST(NULL AS BIGINT),-2))`

or is there any other way ?

If I am using `javax.sql.DataSource` program works, but I can not use `setClientProgramName`.

In maven pom :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcc</artifactId>
        <version>11.5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: please edit your question to specify the exact version of the db2jcc*.jar you are using, along with the plain text output of the `db2level` command on the Db2-server.   Current versions support a connection property `ApplicationName` string (up to 255 characters)

Comment: db2level: command not found
``
``
db2ls 
Install Path                       Level   Fix Pack   Special Install Number   Install Date                  Installer UID 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/opt/xxx/db2/V11.1               11.1.1.1        1                            Fri Aug 23 xx:xx:xx 2019 CEST             0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Client info properties support by the IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=pecidscip-client-info-properties-support-by-data-server-driver-jdbc-sqlj).

```
ApplicationName
ClientAccountingInformation
ClientHostname
ClientUser
```

These properties mentioned at the link above can't be set with URL.
They can be set with the JDBC 4 method (use `db2jcc4.jar`, not `db2jcc.jar` which is JDBC 3 implementation) `setClientInfo` **only** like below:

```
conn = ds.getConnection();
conn.setClientInfo("ApplicationName", "MyApplication");
```

Comment: It does not set ``APPLICATION_NAME`` but ``CLIENT_APPLNAME``, which is fine also. Thanks